# Compare String with Regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a list of string taken from a file. Some of this strings are in the format "Q" + number + "null" (e.g. Q98null, Q1null, Q24null, etc)

With a foreach loop I must check if a string is just like the one shown before.
I use this right now

```
string a = "Q9null" //just for testing
if(a.Contains("Q") && a.Contains("null"))
  MessageBox.Show("ok");
```

but I'd like to know if there is a better way to do this with regex.
Thank you!

Comment: try using pattern Q*.?null

Comment: Regex is the sensible choice, just note that using .StartsWith("Q") .EndsWidth("null") instead of .Contains would avoid false positives.

Comment: @WholsRich, but that cannot guarantee what's between "Q" and "null"

Comment: Yes, Regex is great for when you definitely need something a particular format, it was just something to keep in mind as you can find yourself doing a quick one time data filter, and a simple Char.IsDigit(a, 1) is good enough.

Answer (score 3):

Your method will produce a lot of false positives - for example, it would recognize some invalid strings, such as `"nullQ"` or `"Questionable nullability"`.

A regex to test for the match would be `"^Q\\d+null$"`. The structure is very simple: it says that the target string must start in a `Q`, then one or more decimal digits should come, and then there should be `null` at the end.

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("Q123null", "^Q\\d+null$")); // Prints True
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("nullQ", "^Q\\d+null$"));    // Prints False
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/I8fK2k)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static bool Check(string s)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"^Q\d+null$");
    Match match = regex.Match(s);
    return match.Success;
}
```

Apply the above method in your code:

```
string a = "Q9null" //just for testing
if(Check(a))
  MessageBox.Show("ok");
```

Answer (score 0):

**First way: Using the Regex**

Use this Regex `^Q\d+null$`

**Second way: Using the SubString**

```
string s = "Q1123null";
string First,Second,Third;
First = s[0].ToString();
Second = s.Substring(1,s.Length-5);
Third = s.Substring(s.Length-4);
Console.WriteLine (First);
Console.WriteLine (Second);
Console.WriteLine (Third);
```

then you can check everything after this...